# jQuery serialize with Ajax does not work in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

```
function myTimestamp(){  
    tstmp = new Date();      
    return tstmp.getTime(); 
}   
function showValues() {  
    var str = ($("#this").serialize());  
    $("#results").text(str);  
}  
$(":checkbox, :radio").click(showValues);  
$("select").change(showValues);  
showValues();  
function sendValues() {  
    var str = $("#this").serialize();  
    var response = $('input[name=product[]]:checked').val();  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/post.php?avoidcache=' + myTimestamp();",  
        data: {str}  
        cache: false  
    });  
}
```

This script works wonderful in Google Chrome; however when using in IE it only will execute one of the selected elements: the rest of the selected elements get cut off. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> I just found my answer

Comment: Then enter the answer below and check it ;)...or request a question close.

Comment: What is the HTML associated with this code?  (Specifically `#this`)

Comment: Does this bug apply to Firefox 4.0 as well? I think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: I'd recommend against using this because it will force all versions of IE into IE7 mode, which breaks CSS and the box model.